# after updating json array to data-autocomplete it is not updating the value of data-autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I am creating a dynamic form for a hospital. Here i have a problem with data-autocomplete. The problem is after updating json array to **data-autocomplete=' '** it is not updating the value of **data-autocomplete=' '**.
AS I am using html(bootstrap) and php templete for my frontend forms so,all links are properly arrenged and one input element similar to this is working fine but i have updated the values using php for that input.

## Html code

`<input type='text' class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" data-autocomplete='' autocomplete="off" id="patient_type_desc" name="patient_type_desc" class="form-control" />`

## JQuery Code

```
$.post(url, {"referral":referral}, function(data){
   //console.log(data);
   $('#patient_type_desc').attr('data-autocomplete', data);
});
```

This code is updating the value, but in form autocomplete is not populating with suggestions.

> The data variable is like below

```
["name1","name2"]
```

I tried with this jQuery code also but no use - This code not at all working

```
$( "#patient_type_desc" ).autocomplete({
  source: data
});
```

Comment: It might be the type. I think data is an array and .attr might only be able to take strings. I don't see any errors otherwise.

Comment: Hi Fliink thanks for responding for my question. Jquery code is working with array and it is updating to data-autocomplete=' ' but in form its is not in action. This is my problem. Sorry if i said anything woring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Jquery is like this now

```
$.post(url, {"referral":referral}, function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                $( "#patient_type_desc" ).autocomplete({
                    source: data
                });
                    //$('#patient_type_desc').attr('data-autocomplete', data);
                }, "json");
```

Finally working by adding "json". Thank you for all bro's.

Comment: by seeing your **jsFiddle** and also adding this to azax code ` "json" `

Comment: According to the fiddler you changed the format of json object returned by your rest api, Right? Great job man.

Answer (score 4):

Please check below code, find the fiddle also here [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vijuucity/LfvUz/79/)
. Hope this may help you.

```
<div class="form-group ui-widget">
<label for="plugins">Patient Type desc</label>
<input type='text' class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" data-autocomplete='' autocomplete="off" id="patient_type_desc" name="patient_type_desc" class="form-control" />
</div>

<script>
  $(function()   
     var patient_type_desc = [
    "name1",
    "name2",
    "name3",
    "name4"
    ];

    $("#patient_type_desc").autocomplete({source: patient_type_desc});

    $("ul.ui-autocomplete").css("left","450px");

});
</script>

<style>
ul.ui-autocomplete { padding-left: 0; list-style-type: none; border: black 1px solid; display: inline-block;}
ul.ui-autocomplete li:hover { background-color: gray; }
ui-helper-hidden-accessible {display: none;}
</style>
```

Comment: Using - $("#plugins").autocomplete({source: plugin_names});           This is way is not at all working bro

Comment: @Rajasekhar Did you checked the fiddle mentioned above? Its working there. Which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: @Rajasekhar I have updated the code and fiddle with the control names as you mentioned on the question. Is this ok?

Comment: **Thanks bro** finally this method works. I am trying with **azax** there i forget to make the variable as **Json Object**.